# Deadlock with Multiple goroutines with multiple channels

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am working on a sample program to print sum of odd and sum of even number between 1 to 100 using goroutine with multiple channels.

you can find my code

[here](https://play.golang.org/p/5OSqFEKjIgf)

output

```
sum of even number = 2550
sum of odd number = 2500
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.print(0x434100, 0x11db7c)
    /tmp/sandbox052575152/main.go:18 +0xc0
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox052575152/main.go:14 +0x120
```

The code works but with deadlock.
I am not sure what is wrong in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can iterate through values sent over a channel. To break such iteration channel needs to be closed explicitly. Otherwise range would block forever in the same way as for nil channel. In your code you did't close the `sum`(for print function `sumValues` channel) channel. That's why following function will be blocked for forever.

```
func print(sumValues <-chan string ){
    for val := range sumValues {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

So you have to close the `sum` channel in the `doSum` function after all the go routine in the `doSum` function are complete (otherwise `sum` channel might be closed before go routines are complete). You can use `sync.WaitGroup` to do that. See the updated `doSum` function below:

```
func doSum(sum chan<- string, oddChan <-chan int, evenChan <-chan int) {
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

    waitGroup.Add(2) // Must wait for 2 calls to 'done' before moving on

    go func(sum chan<- string) {
        s1 := 0
        for val := range oddChan {
            s1 += val
        }
        sum <- fmt.Sprint("sum of odd number = ", s1)
        waitGroup.Done()
    }(sum)

    go func(sum chan<- string) {
        s1 := 0
        for val := range evenChan {
            s1 += val
        }
        sum <- fmt.Sprint("sum of even number = ", s1)
        waitGroup.Done()
    }(sum)

    // Waiting for all goroutines to exit
    waitGroup.Wait()

    // all goroutines are complete now close the sum channel
    close(sum)
}
```

Comment: Where should close `sum` channel?  at the end of `doSum` function?